# Restricting Web navigation with Joomla! login in a Cybercafe

Tags: login

Want to integrate all desktops on our cafe with username and password such that anyone accessing computer has to login through our website. Is it possible? This will help us having an email list of customers while making them aware of our website.

Comment: Are you referring to computers within a cybercafe? If so, are you referring to the same sort of system some restaurants use where you have to sign up for some cloud account to be able to access the wifi?

Comment: If @Lodder is write then this question has not much todo with Joomla because this could not be done with a Website only. Please add more information whats your plan is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to force all users to have a certain cookie (session).

A local proxy can redirect users to your local website, until the user login and generates the required cookie. Once users are logged in, they can freely navigate through the proxy.

BTW: This is not a Joomla! specific question... more related with cybercafes!